# Casting an array of chars to ints on a hashtable

Tags: java, casting, char, int

This is a question regarding casting of types in Java.

```
public int hashFunction(String D){
    char[] Thing = D.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0; i < Thing.length; i++){
        index =+(int)Thing.length;
    }
    return index % tablesize;
}
```

Now how does the code work such that each content of the **char** array is now cast to a type **int**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java will allow you to assign `char`s to `int`s, since `int` has a larger domain than `char`.  This is known as **widening**:

```
char c = 'a';
int i = c; // compiles just fine
```

You probably want to access each element in `Thing`, right?  Use an enhanced for loop:

```
for(char c : Thing) {
  // do something with c
}
```